# Detecting if a front end token is available to execute

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematica-frontend

How can I detect if a [front end token](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/FrontEndTokens.html) is available to execute?  Alternately, how can I detect if a front end token failed to execute?

Example: the Edit -> Copy command is not available if nothing is selected.  `FrontEndTokenExecute["Copy"]` will simply beep in this case, but it gives me no (programmatic) indication that it has failed.

Comment: Your question made me wonder if I could find an undocumented Q function, so I evaluated ?*`*Q and found NotebookTools`CellsSelectedQ. (I have not tried using it; dunno exactly how this is supposed to be evaluated.) Also see my comment on Sjoerd's answer regarding hiding the message window. Finally, you might also hunt through ?FrontEnd*`* and ?FrontEnd`*`*Q* for more ideas.

Comment: @telefunkenvf14 Interesting find! There seem to be several useful functions in ``NotebookTools` ``.  I can't use this because it only returns `True` if full cells are selected (not just text in the cells), but looking at the source is already good inspiration.  Perhaps I can come up with something more efficient than `NotebookRead@SelectedNotebook[]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a method to deal with your second question, but it's not elegant:

1. In `Preferences > Interface > Message and Warning actions` set *Minor user interface warnings* to *Beep and Print to Console*
2. Make sure there is at least one error message in the message window
3. Obtain a handle to the message window notebook (using `Notebooks[]` or so)
4. Store the last cell in the message notebook using 
   `NotebookGet[NotebookObject[FrontEndObject[LinkObject["55d_shm", 1, 1]], 1]]/. Notebook[{___, Cell[a___]}, ___] :> Cell[a]` (your handle will look differently, of course)
5. Your call: FrontEndTokenExecute["Copy"]
6. Get the last error message and check whether it differs from the one stored in step 4.
7. The error cell looks like `Cell["You tried to edit a cell that is not editable. You can make the \
   cell editable by choosing Cell Editable in the Cell Properties \
   submenu.", "Message", "Message", "MSG", PageWidth -> WindowWidth, 
   ShowCellLabel -> True, CellChangeTimes -> {3.534442831*10^9}, 
   CellTags -> "cantEditLockedCell"]`
8. Act appropriately

Comment: Interesting hack. Suggestion: Couldn't you also set the message window to be hidden? Not sure if this is possible or not. (i.e., global properties may not allow it.)

Comment: Thanks Sjoerd!  I was looking for a solution that will just work on any system without additional setup, so finally I gave up on this, and I tried `NotebookRead@SelectedNotebook[]` to just test if there is a selection.  The drawback of this method is that it is possible that the selection contains a huge amount of data, and it might be slow to retrieve (e.g. when too much output is generated and Mathematica wraps it in that "show more/less" box)